# Two column glossary

Tags: two-column, glossaries

I'm having a problem similar to this: [Two-column longtable or tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/two-column-longtable-or-tabular).  I want the same result -- that is a two column glossary (ie a total of 4 columns) where a list of abbreviations and their descriptions wraps into a new, second column on the same page before continuing overleaf.  However, I'm using the `glossaries` package.  I've scanned the (very long) documentation and the only references to columns I can find is in the sense of adding more information (i.e. symbols) to a single glossary column.  Does anyone know if there's a way to do what I'm asking?

By the by: I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the page header for the glossary read in all-caps (like every other page header).  Redefining the `\glossarymark` command as anything leaves me with a "CONTENTS" page header, flowing over from the ToC which is immediately before my glossary.

Edit: Not sure how much multiple questions are appreciated, but since these are all style related I have one more -- is there a style for the glossary that is similar/identical to the TOC?  All the styles that come with the package appear to suck... the closest to what I want (extremely simple) is the long style, but for some reason it is indented like 1.5 in and looks hideous.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that is, at least your preamble and some blind text with a glossary example? That way I could copy and paste the code, and start improving on it ;)

Comment: glossaries has many different styles that support longtable, supertabular and two column lists. you can even write your own style. Have another look in chapter 3 of the manual or provide an example

Comment: The `glossary-mcols` package supplies some styles that use `multicols`. This package comes with `glossaries` but isn't automatically loaded.

Answer (score 18):

Since I battled with this a while as well and I couldn't find any helpful discussions on the web, I just read carefully the manual! Maybe this is a feature newer than this topic, so it wasn't around the days the question was asked. But I like to provide an easy way to achieve multiple columns with the `glossaries` package so that others might find a solution faster.
One only needs the additional `glossary-mcols` package which provides exactly that.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{} % Removes dots at the end of each entry.

\begin{document}

% Some entries.
\newglossaryentry{glos:begin}{name=Begin, description={This is the beginning.}}
\newglossaryentry{glos:bold}{name=Bold, description=\nopostdesc}
\newglossaryentry{glos:bear}{name=Bear, description={A bear can make you run fast.}}\newglossaryentry{glos:chicken}{name=Chicken, description={Tasty...}}
\newglossaryentry{glos:elephant}{name=Elephant, description=\nopostdesc}
\newglossaryentry{glos:tantalos}{name=Tantalos, description={Just a random name.}}
\newglossaryentry{glos:zebra}{name=Zebra, description=\nopostdesc}

% Use the entries so that they show up in the glossary.
\gls{glos:begin}
\gls{glos:bold}
\gls{glos:bear}
\gls{glos:chicken}
\gls{glos:elephant}
\gls{glos:tantalos}
\gls{glos:zebra}

% Print the glossary with one of the mcol styles.
\printglossary[style=mcolindex, title=Index]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to consider your own answer :).

Comment: @DaPhil I will just add some info about how to get a pdf: for example in TexLive I need `pdflatex filename`, `makeglossaries filename`, `pdflatex filename` where `filename` is the LaTeX filename without `.tex` extension.

Comment: Note that the dots can also be removed by the package option `nopostdot`.

Answer (score 8):

With regard to your first question (how to achieve a two-column glossary): Here's a solution using the `labeling` list environment provided by [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)'s `scrextend` package. Note that you have to provide the longest label ("electrolyte" in my example) as argument to `\begin{labeling}`. It is also necessary to hack some `glossaries` internals to prevent `\printglossaries` from typesetting a heading automatically -- instead, a heading is added manually in the optional argument of `\begin{multicols}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrextend}% provides the "labeling" environment

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{labeling}{%
  \renewcommand{\theglossary}{\begin{labeling}{electrolyte\quad}}%
  \renewcommand{\endtheglossary}{\end{labeling}}%
}
\glossarystyle{labeling}

\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,%
    description={solution able to conduct electric current}}
\newglossaryentry{tex.sx}{name=tex.sx,%
    description={a website for enthusiastic users of \TeX, \LaTeX\ and related systems}}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{25pt}

% Don't typeset a glossary heading automatically
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@glossarysection}[2]{%
\ifx\@@glossarysecstar\@empty
%  \csname\@@glossarysec\endcsname{#2}% DELETED
\else
%  \csname\@@glossarysec\endcsname*{#2}% DELETED
  \@gls@toc{#1}{\@@glossarysec}%
\fi
\@@glossaryseclabel}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text about \gls{electrolyte} and \gls{tex.sx}.

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\glossaryname}]
\printglossaries
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `lockstep`'s answer shows you how to customize _everything_, but if you decide you like any of the standard styles and just want to insert the `multicols` environment, you can use the `etoolbox` package to insert the `multicols` environment: `\newglossarystyle{twocollist}{\glossarystyle{list}\BeforeBeginEnvironment{theglossary}{\begin{multicols}{2}}\AfterEndEnvironment{theglossary}{\end{multicols}}}`.  This would simply embed the `list` style in a two-column display.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. I've tried Keks Dose's suggestion, but it was unsatisfactory because the title of the Glossary (chapter, in my case) was made part of the `multicols`, too. However, defining a new glossary style (based on `list`, in my case) which has a `{multicols}{2}`-Environment wrapped around the standard `description`, solves this issue:

```
\newglossarystyle{mylist}{
\glossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{
\begin{multicols}{2}\begin{description}}{\end{description}\end{multicols}} 
% the default environment for list is \begin{description} \end{description}
} 
\printglossary[style=mylist]
```

Edit: I just realized that this kind of solution was almost provided in a comment to a previous answer. mforbes' solution uses `BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `AfterEndEnvironment` from the `etoolbox` package. My solution is based on knowing the default environment of the style you are modifying, but doesn't need an extra package. mforbes' solution is agnostic of the value of `theglossary`

Comment: Perfect. Someone select this answer. By far the simplest.

Answer (score 3):

This answer has the duplicate [glossaries: multi-column and indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98751/21591) in mind (@bioslime), where a `mcolalttree` glossary was used, but with the requirement to have a tabular-like look. It is established by adding a single line to the existing `mcolalttree` style:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

  \usepackage[numberline,acronym]{glossaries}
  \usepackage{glossary-mcols}

  \glssetwidest{DIEASSD}% widest name - works with altree style


\makeatletter
  %%
  %% modification of mcolalttree;
  %% everything taken verbatim from mcolalttree, exception indicated
  %%
  \newglossarystyle{mymcolalttree}{%
    \glossarystyle{alttree}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
      {%
        \begin{multicols}{2}%
        \def\@gls@prevlevel{-1}%
        \mbox{}\par
      }%
      {\par\end{multicols}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
      \ifnum\@gls@prevlevel=0
      \hangindent\glstreeindent%%%%%%%%%%%%%% this has been added
      \else
        \settowidth{\glstreeindent}{\textbf{\@glswidestname\space}}%
        \hangindent\glstreeindent
        \parindent\glstreeindent
      \fi
      \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\glstreeindent][l]{%
        \glsentryitem{##1}\textbf{\glstarget{##1}{##2}}}}%
      \ifx\relax##4\relax
      \else
        (##4)\space
      \fi
      ##3\glspostdescription \space ##5\par
      \def\@gls@prevlevel{0}%
    }%
  }%
\makeatother

  % stops gaps between groups
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
  \usepackage{showframe}

  \makeglossaries

  \newacronym{a}{SER}{somesthing.}
  \newacronym{b}{BEB}{an awesome acronym.}
  \newacronym{c}{CCED}{yet another extended acronym description.}
  \newacronym{d}{DIEASSD}{the story about a fork, knife and a table full of spoons.}
  \newacronym{e}{IAIAIA}{short one with with with some some text text text extends.}
  \newacronym{f}{FAF}{this is a very long description for an acronym which is totally awesome.}
  \newacronym{g}{FAF2}{this is a very elaborate description for an acronym which is beyond awesome.}
  \newacronym{h}{IA}{short one again.this is a very long description. this is a very long description.}

  \begin{document}
  \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=mymcolalttree]
  Here are the acronyms: \gls{a}, \gls{b}, \gls{c}, \gls{d}, \gls{e}, \gls{f},
  \gls{h}, \gls{g}.%, \gls{i}.

  \end{document}
```

[image: two-column glossary]

Answer (score 1):

Can't your question be answered by simply using the `multicol` package and writing:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\glossary
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Was this supposed to be a comment?

Comment: Problem is it crams a chapter heading into the multicolumns

Answer (score 1):

the `amsbook` document class defines a two-column index with a one-column chapter heading.  this code is taken from there.

```
\newif\if@restonecol
\def\indexchap#1{\global\topskip 7.5pc\relax
  \twocolumn[{\fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bfseries\centering
    \vskip\topskip\hbox{}\vskip-\baselineskip% adjust top space
    #1\par
   \global\topskip 34\p@\relax
   \ifx\@empty\indexintro
   \else
     \begingroup \normalsize
       \skip@\topskip \advance\skip@ -\baselineskip
       \vskip\skip@
       \parbox[t]{24pc}{\normalfont\indexintro\par}%
     \endgroup
     \global\topskip 24\p@\relax
   \fi
  }]%
}
\newcommand{\indexintro}{}
\newcommand{\@indextitlestyle}{%
  \let\@makeschapterhead\indexchap
  \@xp\chapter\@xp*\@xp{\indexname}%
}
\def\theindex{\@restonecoltrue\if@twocolumn\@restonecolfalse\fi
  \columnseprule\z@ \columnsep 35\p@
  \@indextitlestyle
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  ...
}
\def\indexname{Index}
```

`\indexchap` is the component that sets the heading in a single column, and the switch `\if@restonecol` is what is used to determine whether the page continues as one column or two.  this code was adapted from `book.cls` but made more modular.  comparing this with what's in `book.cls` should be enough to help you create a similar `theglossary` environment for your multi-chapter document.  (it's not suitable for an article.)

Comment: The "hard part" of the OP's question is defining a "tabular-like"  environment that is compatible with `twocolumn` mode.

Comment: @lockstep -- part of the question was how to get the proper running head.  using a chapter-based approach gets rid of that automatically.  and since this approach makes each column a page, `longtable` should work without problems as well.  if i have time tomorrow, i'll try to put together a working example.