# Balance/flush columns at the end of each chapter in twocolumn layout

Tags: vertical-alignment, chapters, two-column

In a `twocolumn` layout, how can I balance columns at the end of each chapter?

- Package `multicol` is not appreciated because it doesn't offer nice float placement in the columns (floats are not allowed inside `multicols` 
  environment, `[H]` placement is not floating)
- Package `flushend` does the jobs, but only for the last page of the document... why not for the last page of every chapter ?
- FWIW, every chapter of my document starts on a new page
- FWIW, I use the `memoir` class, but I don't think it matters here

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate more on the "[not] nice float placement" when using [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol)? Column balancing is what `multicol` was written for, so it may be your only way out.

Comment: Added explanation: "floats are not allowed inside multicols environment, [H] placement is not floating"

Comment: [Frank Mittelbachs answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57750/5049) to [Placing figures inside a two-column document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30812/5049) might be of interest for you.

Answer (score 4):

You may use `balance` package (though you have to insert `\balance` manually some where in the first column of last page of each chapter)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\lipsum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adip-
iscing elit.
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat
ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.
\balance                         %%% Note this line here
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, con-
sectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula
augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tris-
tique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhon-
cus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla
ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida
placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis,
viverra ac, nunc.
Praesent eget sem vel leo ultri-
ces bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla,
malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
Cur-
abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget
risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend,
sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dig-
nissim rutrum.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollic-
itudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam
lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus.
Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan biben-
dum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat,
congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero.
Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy
pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit.
Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis,
molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maece-
nas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan
nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat
magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia
nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel
magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc
eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam
cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulpu-
tate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu
massa.
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh.
Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

\chapter{Two}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's not very practical to place the `\balance` command manually because the first column of last page is not easily known in the latex source.

Comment: Also, I ran your exact example and did not get the same output: I got a vertical offset of about one line between the top of the two columns on pages 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Be careful! The baselines are uneven (See about 10 lines down on the right column). I very doubt anyone would prefer this outcome to uneven columns.