# Glossary with Makeglos no numbered in 2 columns

Tags: glossaries, bold, columns

I would like to know how to put my glossary in two columns and without page numbers and the acronym in bold letters like this

> **UAV** : Unmanned Air Vehicle

This is my code

```
\usepackage{makeglos}
\makeglossary

\glossary{UAV: Unmanned Air Vehicle |textbf} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossary}
\printglossary
```

Comment: \usepackage{multicol}                                         \begin{multicols}{2}
\printglossary
\end{multicols}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an old outdated package I recommend the usage of the modern and comfortable package `glossaries`. Providing a two column glossar with glossaries see [Two column glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30812/two-column-glossary)