# glossaries: multi-column and indentation

Tags: indentation, glossaries, acronyms

I want to achieve a two column acronym list with `glossaries`. Using the `mcolalttree` version of `alttree` allows to define the indentation with `\glssetwidest{}`. Unfortunately after a line break the indentation is not taking place but text starts from the beginning. I would like the text to always be aligned right of the indentation (marked line).
The style `long` has this alignment yet it cannot be used in a `multicol` environment.

[image: acronyms alignment]

Code:

```
  \documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

  \usepackage[xindy,nostyles,numberline,acronym]{glossaries}
  \usepackage{glossary-mcols}
  \glossarystyle{mcolalttree}
  \glssetwidest{DIEASSD}% widest name - works with altree style

  % stops gaps between groups
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
  \usepackage{showframe}

  \makeglossaries

  \newacronym{a}{SER}{somesthing.}
  \newacronym{b}{BEB}{an awesome acronym.}
  \newacronym{c}{CCED}{yet another extended acronym description.}
  \newacronym{d}{DIEASSD}{the story about a fork, knife and a table full of spoons.}
  \newacronym{e}{IAIAIA}{short one with with with some some text text text extends.}
  \newacronym{f}{FAF}{this is a very long description for an acronym which is totally awesome.}
  \newacronym{g}{FAF2}{this is a very elaborate description for an acronym which is beyond awesome.}
  \newacronym{h}{IA}{short one again.this is a very long description. this is a very long description.}


  \begin{document}
  \printglossaries
  Here are the acronyms: \gls{a}, \gls{b}, \gls{c}, \gls{d}, \gls{e}, \gls{f},
  \gls{h}, \gls{g}.
  \end{document}
```

Comment: I added an [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98993/21591) for you at the duplicate question.