# \BeforeBeginEnvironment not doing anything?

Tags: environments, glossaries, multicol, etoolbox

I'm attempting to do something similar to [Two column glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30812/two-column-glossary), making an extant glossary style wrap into multiple columns. I've followed the suggestion in the comment to the first answer, i.e. use `etoolbox` to put the `theglossary` environment inside `\multicols`. The problem is, only the `\AfterEndEnvironment` seems to be doing anything. This code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
    \setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}
\newacronym{acr}{acr}{Acronym}
\makeglossaries
\newglossarystyle{twocollong}{
    \glossarystyle{long}
    \BeforeBeginEnvironment{thegl‌​ossary}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
    \AfterEndEnvironment{theglossary}{\end{multicols}}
    }
\begin{document}
Text text 
\acrshort{acr} 
text text

\printglossary[style=twocollong]

\end{document}
```

gives me the error that '`\begin{document}` is ended by `\end{multicols}`'. Commenting out only the `\AfterEndEnvironment` line (and leaving in `\BeforeBeginEnvironment`) gives me a working document - no errors about `\begin{multicols}` being ended by `\end{document}`. It seems as if `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` isn't inserting anything at all.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have two invisible characters between `thegl` and `ossary` in the argument to `\BeforeBeginEnvironment`. In any case this won't work, because the `long` glossary style uses `longtable` that can't be used in a `multicols` environment.

Comment: ...now I'm getting an 'environment `\multicols` undefined' error, even using `list` instead of `long`.

Comment: Of course you need `\usepackage{multicol}`.

Comment: Why not just use one of the styles defined in `glossary-mcols.sty` described in the [Multicols Style section](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:mcolstyles) of the user manual?

Comment: Those don't quite look like what I'm wanting, since I want the definitions in a separate column. I may have no choice, though, if I can't wrap `long`. (I don

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following defines a new glossary style based on `mcoltree` that produces a tabular-like appearance:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\makeglossaries

\newlength\acrwidth

\appto\newacronymhook{%
  \settowidth{\acrwidth}{\textsc{\the\glsshorttok}}%
  \addtolength{\acrwidth}{1em}%
  \ifdim\acrwidth>\glstreeindent
    \setlength{\glstreeindent}{\acrwidth}%
  \fi
}

\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}

\newacronym{acr}{acr}{Acronym}
\newacronym{acr2}{acr2}{Acronym2}
\newacronym{acr3}{acr3}{Acronym3}
\newacronym{acr4}{acr4}{Acronym4}
\newacronym{acr5}{acr5}{Acronym5}
\newacronym{acr6}{acr6}{Acronym6}
\newacronym{acr7}{acr7}{Acronym7}
\newacronym{acr8}{acr8}{Acronym8}
\newacronym{acr9}{acr9}{Acronym9}
\newacronym{acr10}{acr10}{Acronym10}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{mcoltree}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \hangindent\glstreeindent\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \makebox[\glstreeindent][l]{%
       \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2\par
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Text text 
text text
\glsaddall

\printglossary[style=mystyle]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of resulting glossary]

Comment: This is exactly what I was wanting! Thank you!