# glossaries \glstreeindent not working in alttree style

Tags: glossaries

I am experimenting with the pre-defined glossary style in the `glossaries` package. The tree style looks great and seems flexible, but I would like the left edge of all the glossary entries to line up vertically down the page. As far as I can tell, that is what the alttree style is for.

But when I use alttree, the glossary entry name and description overlap. Is that expected behavior? I suspect that \glstreeindent is not indenting properly. If it is expected behavior, what am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%

\usepackage[style=alttree]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{gls1}{name={gls1},description={description for gls1}}
\newglossaryentry{gls2}{name={gls2},description={description for gls2}}
\newglossaryentry{gls3}{name={gls3longname},description={description for gls3}}

\glsaddall
\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

I have tried modifying the alttree style to add `\hangindent\glstreeindent` after the line `\ifnum\@gls@prevlevel=0` (as per [mfap's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98993/6665) to this [Two column glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30812/two-column-glossary) question) but there is no change in output.

(Tried to tag with [alttree] and [tree] but I don't have permissions yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set width manually: use `\glssetwidest{}` in the preamble. This command takes one argument and sets the name box width to the width of that argument.

To semi-automatically determine width: use `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname` in the preamble. This iterates over all glossaries (using `\forallglossaries`) and finds the widest parentless glossary entry name.

It can take an optional argument which is a list of glossary names to iterate over. For instance, `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[main,acronym]` will find the widest parentless glossary entry name in the acronym and main glossaries only.

Comment: You can iterate through the gls entries with `\forglsentries` in order to determine the widest entry (see the `glossaries` documentation about `\forglsentries`

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianHupfer. I had trouble using `\forglsentries` in this fashion, but it looks like `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname` basically does this anyway. Just what I needed.

Do you want to make your suggestion and/or `\glsfindwidesttoplovelname` an answer? It is exactly what I was looking for with my question.

Comment: No, keep your answer or add your findings to it.